.NET MAUI WebView displays content in Debug config but is blank in Release config
My .NET MAUI app displays content through the WebView control such as embedded X (Twitter) posts. This works fine on Android when debugging the app. However, with Release configuration the WebView does not display content at all. What could be the cause of this?

Is the source "http"? Have you set UseClearTextTraffic to true? Are you sure you have height and width set to non-zero? Do you know the difference between url and html source?

@H.A.H. everything works fine when I debug, so I believe the implementation is fine (height, width). I have also set UseClearTextTraffic to true.

Is there an easy way to reproduce this?

Yes. The article referenced by Jessie Zang in his answer actually acknowledges this issue but the solution provided is not up to date.

You can try to disable linking in the Release configuration. Linking is a process that removes unused code from your application to reduce its size. However, it can also remove code that is needed for the WebView control to work correctly.
For more information, please check :Linking a .NET MAUI Android app and Linking a .NET MAUI Android app.
And there is an article about this, you can check it here: MAUI WebView Displays Content: Debug vs Release Configurations.

Thank you for this. The article is pointing in the right direction but is outdated due to MAUI's migration from ViewRenderers to ViewHandlers. I'm running .net 8 and this solution does not fit. Any up to date versions of this solution would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Have you tried to disable the trimming option for release builds?

Yes, I've tried disabling the trimming. My apk is larger and still it doesn't work.

Have you tried to  re-enabled the GC option?

I found the solution to my problem. For some reason, the data type I passed into the Source attribute of the WebView was not being recognized as a string even though it actually is. Specifying x:DataType="x:String" solved the problem. See code below.
   <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PostEmbedTemplate" x:DataType="x:String">
            <WebView Source="{Binding}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" MinimumHeightRequest="720" HeightRequest="720" MaximumHeightRequest="1000" Margin="0,15" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="VideoEmbedTemplate" x:DataType="x:String">
            <mct:MediaElement Source="{Binding}" ShouldKeepScreenOn="True" HeightRequest="400" ShouldLoopPlayback="False" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="0,15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <selectors:EmbedDisplaySelector   
           x:Key="EmbedDisplaySelector"
           PostEmbedTemplate="{StaticResource PostEmbedTemplate}"
           VideoEmbedTemplate="{StaticResource VideoEmbedTemplate}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>

